# Problem with using IntersectionObserver to trigger CSS animation

Tags: javascript, css

I am trying to use IntersectionObserver to observe the 3 `container` so that the `wipe-enter` animation will start when they are inside the viewport one by one.

If I scroll to a `container` (that is outside the viewport) slowly so that only part of it is inside the viewport, the `container` keeps flickering until it is fully inside the viewport.

I tried to inspect the `container` when it is flickering and it seems that the `container-animation` class is being added and removed constantly until the `container` is fully inside the viewport.

This is the first time I use IntersectionObserver so I am not sure how the code should be changed to stop them from flickering.

Any help will be appreciated. Thank you.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Animation</title>
    <style>
        .container {
            width: 300px;
            height: 300px;
            background: green;
            margin: 500px auto;
        }

        @keyframes wipe-enter {
            0% { transform: scale(0, .025); }
            50% { transform: scale(1, .025); }
        }

        .container-animation {
            animation: wipe-enter 1s 1;
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="container"></div>    
    <div class="container"></div>    
    <div class="container"></div>    
</body>

<script>
    // Register IntersectionObserver
    const io = new IntersectionObserver(entries => {
    entries.forEach(entry => {
        // Add 'container-animation' class if observation target is inside viewport
        if (entry.intersectionRatio > 0) {
            entry.target.classList.add('container-animation');
        }
        else {
            // Remove 'container-animation' class
            entry.target.classList.remove('container-animation');
        }
    })
    })

    // Declares what to observe, and observes its properties.
    const containers = document.querySelectorAll('.container');
    containers.forEach((el) => {
        io.observe(el);
    })
</script>
</html>
```

Comment: Could you describe a bit more what effect you want? Is the element to go to full width in half a second, and then to full height by the end of the second even though only a few pixels may be showing in the viewport (ie the user may not see much animation)?

Comment: It's worth thinking through what scale actually does. It scales by default from the center so when you scale it down the element goes out of the viewport again so you remove the animation, then immediately put it back on etc etc.

Comment: Ideas on how to solve this (didn't test it): Increase the margin for the Intersection Observer. Or unobserve the element when you add the class, add the observer back after 1s or so if you need the effect again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When an element is scaled it still 'takes up' the same space in the page - in the sense that other items are not affected. However, scaling takes place by default from the central point of the element.

So, when an element gets into the viewport your code immediately scales it right down and then gradually increases its height but from the center which will at that time be nearly 150px below (or above) the viewport bottom/top.

So you get told it's gone out of the viewport and you remove the animation. The element goes back to 300px high and so enters the viewport and so on. Hence 'flashing'.

One way to prevent this is to not remove the animation when the item goes out of the viewport but when the animation has finished - then it doesn't matter that it's shrunk through the scaling and isn't in the viewport for part of a second.

But, in order to prevent other elements moving we can't just do this by changing the height of the element, that needs to remain constant. This code scales a before pseudo element on each of the containers.

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Animation</title>
    <style>
        .container {
            width: 300px;
            height: 300px;
            margin: 500px auto;
            position: relative;
        }

        @keyframes wipe-enter {
            0% { transform: scale(0, .025); }
            50% { transform: scale(1, .025); }
            100% { transform: scale(1, 1); }
        }
        .container::before {
          content: '';
          position: absolute;
          width: 100%;
          height: 100%;
          left: 0;
          top: 0;
          background: green;
        }

        .container.container-animation::before {
            animation: wipe-enter 1s 1;
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="container"></div>    
    <div class="container"></div>    
    <div class="container"></div>    
</body>

<script>
    // Register IntersectionObserver
    const io = new IntersectionObserver(entries => {
    entries.forEach(entry => {
        // Add 'container-animation' class if observation target is inside viewport
        if (entry.intersectionRatio > 0) {
            entry.target.classList.add('container-animation');
        }
    })
    })

    // Declares what to observe, and observes its properties.
    const containers = document.querySelectorAll('.container');
    containers.forEach((el) => {
        io.observe(el);
        el.addEventListener('animationend', function () {
          el.classList.remove('container-animation');
        });
    })
</script>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you very much! I added a div outside each container and it is now working as expected. Did not know that the height would affect the intersection!

Comment: My snippet had got corrupted (I didn't patch it in correctly). I've replaced it with the code so you can see how it uses a pseudo element. If you do this you don't have to add extra elements to the actual HTML.

Comment: Thank you. This is a more neat solution without having to add DIVs and break my other CSS codes.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution after reading A Haworth's answer.
I also changed the opacity so that the container does not show up initially.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Animation</title>
    <style>
        .container {
            width: 300px;
            height: 300px;
            background: green;
            margin: 500px auto;
            opacity: 0;
        }

        @keyframes wipe-enter {
            0% {
                transform: scale(0, .025);
            }
            50% {
                transform: scale(1, .025); 
            }
            100% {
                opacity: 1; 
            }
        }

        .container-animation {
            animation: wipe-enter 1s 1;
            animation-fill-mode: forwards;
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="container-wrapper">
        <div class="container"></div>    
    </div>
    <div class="container-wrapper">
        <div class="container"></div>    
    </div>
    <div class="container-wrapper">
        <div class="container"></div>    
    </div>
</body>

<script>
    // Register IntersectionObserver
    const io = new IntersectionObserver(entries => {
    entries.forEach(entry => {

        const container = entry.target.querySelector('.container');
        
        console.log(entry)
        // Add 'container-animation' class if observation target is inside viewport
        if (entry.intersectionRatio > 0) {
            container.classList.add('container-animation');
        }
        else {
            // Remove 'container-animation' class
            container.classList.remove('container-animation');
        }
    })
    })

    // Declares what to observe, and observes its properties.
    const containers = document.querySelectorAll('.container-wrapper');
    containers.forEach((el) => {
        io.observe(el);
    })
</script>
</html>
```