# Jumpy text fade-in animations triggered by IntersectionObserver

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

I am trying to add a fade-in animation to some divs with text. The issue is very similar to this issue [Problem with using IntersectionObserver to trigger CSS animation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71553185/problem-with-using-intersectionobserver-to-trigger-css-animation).

I followed a guide on setting up an IntersectionObserver to trigger the animation to start (add a css class when appropriate).

The bug I am observing is that occasionally on a mobile device I scroll to a section with text and I see the text in its final position for a fraction of a second before the animation begins.

Can see the issue here: https://main.d3ds1uhq2xz2ld.amplifyapp.com/  (Haven't been able to replicate on desktop).

I am using this scroll animate function to set my IntersectionObserver on all divs with the classname `animate`. When the animate div is within 60px of being on the screen, the observer adds a `active` class to the div. When the div is not intersecting the function removes the `active` class with a 1 second delay.

```
export function scrollAnimation(selector, options = {}) {
  let component = document.querySelectorAll(selector);
  component = Array.from(component);
  component.forEach((comp) => {
    addObserver(comp, options);
  });
}

function addObserver(comp, options) {
  let observer = new IntersectionObserver((entries, observer) => {
    entries.forEach((entry) => {
      if (entry.isIntersecting) {
        entry.target.classList.add("active");
        // observer.unobserve(entry.target);
      } else {
        setTimeout(() => {
          entry.target.classList.remove("active");
        }, "1000");
      }
    });
  }, options);
  observer.observe(comp);
```

I am calling the function in a `useEffect` in the `index.js` file of my app so that I can observe all instances of the `animate` class.

```
useEffect(() => {
    scrollAnimation(".animate", {
      rootMargin: "60px",
    });
    const isVerified = localStorage.getItem("isVerified");
    setIsAgeVerifyModal(!isVerified);
  }, [location]);
```